# Finding Formulas for Events in terms of Probability Functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am working out of Statistical Inference by Casella and have come across an issue in the wording of the problem.  I'm hoping someone can shed some light.

> For events $A$ and $B$, find formulas for the probabilities of the following events in terms of the quantities $P(A), P(B),$ and $P(A\cap B)$.
>
> a)  either $A$ or $B$ or both,
>
> b)  either $A$ or $B$ but not both,
>
> c)  at least one of $A$ or $B$
>
> d)  at most one of $A$ or $B$

So using Set Theory and Probability Function axioms, I deduced that the first formula is $P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ and the second is $P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)$.  My contention is that $a$ and $c$ are equivalent statements as are $b$ and $d$, but something feels fishy in the wording.  I would assume 'either $A$ or $B$ or both' refers to simply $A\cup B$, and this seems true of the wording for part $c$ as well since it could be event $A,B$, or $A\cap B$.

But, $d$ is my problem.  I'm thinking 'at most' means it can't include the intersection.  But couldn't then another event be $(A\cup B)'$, the complement of the union of $A$ and $B$?  It is not mentioned that $P(A\cup B)=1$, so there is that new possibility that wasn't in play for part $c$.  Is this correct thinking?  If so, I'm sure I can work out the details.  I would just like to know if someone can verify my contentions.

Thank you.

Comment: Off to a reasonably good start. But doesn't the event in (d) include the possibility of _neither_?